# Angular - How can I update a subcomponent that takes an input parameter and renders it correctly the first time

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding, frontend

I have the following list of educations:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="5" class="list-scroll">
         <app-education-item *ngFor="let education of loadedEducations"
          (isSelected)="changeSelected(education)"
          [ngClass]="{ selected: education == loadedEducation }"
          [education]="education"
          (isRemoved)="removeEducation(education)"
        ></app-education-item>
      </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

and  is the following component

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'list-item-container-collapsed' : isCollapsed, 'list-item-container': !isCollapsed, 'unselected': !isActive, 'selected': isActive}" (click)="selectEducation()">
    <div class="top-items-container" style="display: flex;">
     <div class="item-text">
     <span class="txt-header">{{educationHeader}}</span>
     <p class="txt-date"> 
         <span>{{startDate}}</span> - 
         <span>{{endDate}}</span>
     </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

the  has the following logic used to show the data taken from the parameter:

```
export class EducationItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  education: Education;
  isCollapsed = false;
  isActive = false;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  educationHeader: string;
  educationDescription: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.education);
    this.startDate = this.education.startDate != '' ? formatDate(this.education.startDate, 'MMM yyyy', 'en-US')
        : formatDate(new Date(), 'MM YYYY', 'en-US') ;
    this.endDate = this.education.endDate != 'present' ? this.endDate = formatDate(this.education.endDate, 'MMM yyyy', 'en-US')
        : this.education.endDate;
    this.educationHeader = this.education.degree == undefined || this.education.description == undefined ? ''
        : this.education.degree + ' at ' + this.education.school;

    if (!this.education.description.enUS && this.education.description.nlNL) {
      this.educationDescription = this.education.description.nlNL;
    } else if (this.education.description.enUS) {
      this.educationDescription = this.education.description.enUS;
    }
}
```

I use a custom event to handle update

```html
@Output() updatedValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  fieldChanged(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.updatedValue.emit(changes);
  }
```

Then I have the following html that I use to manipulate the data:

```
<div class="update-wrap">
        <div class="list-header">Update education</div>
        <div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 input-wrapper">
            <app-input-field
              label="Institution"
              [value]="loadedEducation.school"
              (updatedValue)="loadedEducation.school = $event"
            ></app-input-field>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 input-wrapper date-picker-input">
            <app-input-field
              label="Degree"
              [value]="loadedEducation.degree"
              (updatedValue)="loadedEducation.degree = $event"
            ></app-input-field>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

however the updated data in the fields `[value]="loadedEducation.school" (updatedValue)="loadedEducation.school = $event"` don't bind with the sub component so nothing is showing until I refresh and get the data from the DB.

What are the possibilities that I can try to implement?

I tried implementing ngOnChanges, that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is that `@Input()` is unable to detect changes to the internals of objects and arrays, as they are both [reference types](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/primitive-vs-reference-data-types-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Reference%20data%20types%2C%20unlike%20primitive,all%20other%20types%20of%20objects.). Your `education` property is an object, therefore changes that mutate properties directly such as `education.school = 'newValue'` made in the parent component do not trigger any changes in the property `@Input() education` of the child component

There are a few ways to deal with this, each with their pros and cons:

---

### Pass only the properties you need as primitives

`parent.component.ts`

```
education: Education = <initial-value>
```

`parent.component.html`

```
<app-education-item
  [school]="education.school"
  [degree]="education.degree">
</app-education-item>

<app-input-field
  label="Institution"
  [value]="education.school"
  (updatedValue)="loadedEducation.school = $event">
</app-input-field>
```

`child.component.ts`

```
export class EducationItemComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() school: string;
  @Input() degree: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // will emit whenever .school or .degree is changed in the parent
  }
}
```

**Pros:**

- Simple and intuitive to use, works "as normal"
- No extra boilerplate required to **send** changes into the child component

**Cons:**

- Extra boilerplate required to **receive** changes into the child component. Becomes unwieldly as the number of `@Input`'s grow
- You lose the semantic coupling between the parent and child component which are really bound by a shared interface, i.e. the `Education` interface
- Doesn't scale well if the properties are also reference types, in which case these would also need to be unpacked and passed as primitives

---

### Rebuild object in the parent on change

`parent.component.ts`

```
education: Education = <initial-value>

updateEducation(educationProps: Partial<Education>): Education {
  this.education = {
    ...this.education, // Note: You may want to 'deep clone' your object depending on how nested it is
    ...educationProps
  }
}
```

[Deep clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

`parent.component.html`

```
<app-education-item" [education]="education">
</app-education-item>

<app-input-field
  label="Institution"
  [value]="education.school"
  (updatedValue)="updateEducation({ school: $event }">
</app-input-field>
```

`child.component.ts`

```
export class EducationItemComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() education: Education;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // will emit whenever updateEducation() is called in the parent
  }
}
```

**Pros:**

- Retains use of the `Education` interface, maintaining semantic coupling between the parent and child component
- Promotes use of [immutable objects](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/immutable-objects-are-worth-the-effort-7b1b582e3203) which is a good practice for objects generally
- No extra boilerplate required to **receive** changes into the child component.

**Cons:**

- Extra boilerplate required to **send** changes into the child component, i.e. the creation of a superfluous `updateEducation()` function in the parent

---

### Pass a reactive element into your child component, such as a `BehaviorSubject`, and subscribe to the changes directly

`parent.component.ts`

```
educationSubject: BehaviorSubject<Education> = new BehaviorSubject<Education>( <initial-value> )

updateEducation(educationProps: Partial<Education>): Education {
  const updatedEducation: Education = {
    ...this.education, // Note: You may want to 'deep clone' your object depending on how nested it is
    ...educationProps
  }
  this.educationSubject.next(updatedEducation}
}
```

`parent.component.html`

```
<app-education-item" [education]="education">
</app-education-item>

<ng-container *ngIf="educationSubject | async" as education>
  <app-input-field
    label="Institution"
    [value]="education.school"
    (updatedValue)="updateEducation({ school: $event }">
  </app-input-field>
<ng-container>
```

`child.component.ts`

```
export class EducationItemComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() educationSubject: BehaviorSubject<Education>;
}
```

`child.component.html`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="educationSubject | async" as education>
  <p>{{ education.school }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

**Pros:**

- Gives full control over event emission/subscription. This can be beneficial for any other side effects you wish to trigger in response to
- Can easily be extended to work with many components, e.g. place `educationSubject` in a service and inject the same service into any components which require it
- Also promotes use of [immutable objects](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/immutable-objects-are-worth-the-effort-7b1b582e3203)
- No extra boilerplate required to **receive** changes into the child component

**Cons:**

- Extra boilerplate required to **send** changes into the child component, i.e. the creation of a superfluous `updateEducation()` function in the parent
- Typical limitations of working with reactive code such as only mutating via the stream, needing to be weary of unsubscribing (if not using `| async`) etc

Comment: Thank you! the second approach worked, since i am using a list, i just added that, it also works without ngOnChanges now!

Answer (score 0):

the loadedEducations list doesn't change when you change a property of an item from the list. try to refresh the list (`this.loadedEducations = loadedEducations`) or use state management in your project